# Efficiency with large arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following arrays: `$days_involved`, `$ticketIds`, `$userIds` - these might not look like a arrays but each is an array of type: `array('info', 'info_2' ...);` of up to a size of **1000+**

Now I have an sql function that requires ticket id and user id, the function is called as such: `$this->models->ticketLabour->getLaborInformation($ticketId, $userId);` (<-- the following code sample, returns an associative array) and so I thought I could do this:

```
    $storage = array();
    foreach($days_involved as $day){
        foreach($ticketIds as $ticketId){
            foreach($userIds as $userId){
                $storage[$day][$userid][] = $this->models->ticketLabour->getLaborInformation($ticketId, $userId);
            }
        }
    }
```

That looks ok in my eyes ..... till you run it .... and chrome or apache or both crash epically...

How can I do this.....If I can do this.... I have tried looking at the underlying sql statement and I have optimized it as much as possible to get ONLY the information I want...

But at the end of the day even:

```
    foreach($days_involved as $day){
        foreach($ticketIds as $ticketId){
            foreach($userIds as $userId){
                echo "over , and over and, ";
            }
        }
    }
```

epically shatters chrome and apache... (even with: `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);`)

Comment: The thing is that 1000 * 1000 * 1000 makes 1000000000. 1 billion. Do you really have to get so much information at this moment ? If this is about displaying data, do you use everything ? Maybe you could use pagination or something else. Please update your question to add the sql query too.

Comment: Apart from that, you're breaking the *Law of Demeter*

Comment: Its not about displaying it, the data returned is used to create  a CSV (or is it CVS) - All information returned is used - I have simplified the select statements as  much as possible. How ever the data returned is a ton ... Thats why im looking to do this as efficiently as possible if possible.

Comment: Your sql query please... with the data if you wants... would be possible create a query with required result format to avoid recursive methods. I always try go around statements as you're showing.

Comment: I think that the problem is with memory collect the memory usage or set the memory to ini_set('memory_limit', '750M');

Comment: Memory usage is one thing, but how much time will this require? @LogicLooking, please try this out with a smaller set of data and try to estimate the required time. Almost all places where I saw data exporting is done via AJAX, I think that's not a coincidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was mention in the comment try to increase the memory_limit.